# Why does reading PCI device config file freezes the system?

Tags: freeze, arch-linux, nvidia-graphics-card, pci, acpi

I am running Arch Linux, on a Gigabyte Aero 15x v8, and I am confronted to a particularly arduous problem.

To be noted that I am also using bumblebee and bbswitch configured to work with nvidia drivers for the card's power management.

My laptop is affected by the issue described here : [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=156341), and here : [Bumblebee github issue](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/bbswitch/issues/177)

From my understanding it is related to a faulty ACPI portion of code which is executed when trying to change the power state of the card and induces an infinite loop freezing the system, but there isn't a general patch atm because ACPI tables are machine specific (? correct me if I am wrong I am very new to all those subjects and it is still very confusing to me)

Last year I was running Manjaro on a Razer Blade 14 2016 which was affected by the same flaw but fortunately someone had written a patch [here](https://github.com/r0l1/razer_blade_14_2016_acpi_fix)

Now I'd like to patch ACPI tables the same way, and to do so I need to pin down the faulty code.

The bug's symptoms are a complete freeze when running lspci, lshw, or X (the list is non-exhaustive) with neither nouveau or nvidia drivers loaded resulting in a system freeze which leaves no trace in journalctl or dmesg (the losgs just abruptly stop) or by running either of these commands once with nouveau loaded which outputs this message : `pci 0000:01:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3` (among other things then causes the system to shutdown).

So I used strace on lspci which showed me the kernel lockup happened when lspci what trying to read the cards PCI config file (/sys/bus/pci/devices/"card pci adress"/config) and that trying to cat the same file twice resulted in the same crash (lspci calls pread64, and cat uses read on the file, but apprently both acts the same).

Now, I don't understand why reading that config file would crash the system, I think I read somewhere that it's because when doing so the system is trying to power-on the card the power is back off,but unfortunately I can't find the link, could anyone explain to me what is happening here?

I feel like this problem is a bit too complicated for my current competences and that I'll need to do a lot of reading to fix it.